# Close votes not showing, just for one question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

I voted to close this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511079/jquery-ui-dialog-valid-by-jquery-validation

Now I am expecting to see a counter next to the close link:

```
close (1)
```

Instead I just see `close`:

[image]

But I already voted:

[image]

Is there anything besides a bug that would explain this observation?  Strangely, as far as I know, this is only affecting this one question.  (I checked a different one I voted to close and the counter is fine.)

Comment: Could it have been in close-review and marked 'left open' by several reviewers?

Comment: I have no idea.  I have never seen this before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the revisions - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17511079/revisions

You and four others successfully closed the question, but another five users reopened it.

We only allow you to vote once, so this is by design.

(It could be we need better wording on the close popup, though)

Comment: That explains it.  However, I find it very strange that a poorly written/worded and confusing question with few comments would be able to so quickly earn 5 re-open votes.

Comment: Upon its owner editing it, the question was placed in the [Reopen Review Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2461022). We might need to tweak that queue's settings, based on how contentious the review results are.

Comment: Ok, yes, I agree with that.  It seems that people are voting to re-open something who _may_ not fully understand the particular topic and/or that the OP's revision _may_ not be any better than the original.  Also agree that the wording in the initial dialog/popup could be clarified a bit.  Thanks.

Comment: It probably tends to favor 'open', but that's not a bad thing; it's better to have too many open questions than too many closed questions, on the margins.  Generally, close/reopen decision shouldn't require knowing the subject matter.

Comment: In this case, I know the subject matter very well and cannot reconcile the contradictory information given by the OP.  (His code is actually working as expected.)  IMO, the question cannot be answered as presented.

Comment: Your knowledge is not of issue.  The point is that close/reopen decision should be made without knowledge of the subject matter being relevant.  Sure, a bad question might be more obvious to a subject matter expert than to a random Joe, but if it's close enough that a random Joe thinks it should be open, I'm okay with that.

Comment: @Joe, My knowledge is only relevant to the point I was making in my last comment.  IMO, questions that don't make sense, posted with code that's already working the way the OP is requesting, should be closed.  Somebody who understands the code in the question, takes the time to construct a demo, can easily recognize this situation... as did the first five people who voted to close.  The OP's so-called clarification edit is really not much more than a link to another SO answer.